# Is it possible to run a python command within a shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm learning some basic scripting and I thought I would try my hand at "automating" a small task at work and make things a littler easier for users not so comfortable working inside their terminal.

```
    echo "Activating the Bin" 
    Source=source
    BinActivate=/opt/ia3/bin/activate 
    SourceBinActivate=$Source $BinActivate
    if [ pwd == pwd ]
            then
            pwd #Log current directory to console
            sleep 2s
            eval $SourceBinActivate # Run source /opt/ia3/bin/activate
    else
            echo "Error, aborting process";  pwd #exit
    fi
```

When my script runs the eval, my terminal returns an error: /opt/ia3/bin/activate: Permission Denied.

Is it even possible to run a command like this in my terminal? 
Do I need to run this as a specific user? Where should I look to research how to run commands as a user in my terminal?

Any direction or insight is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any Python here...

Comment: Of course it's possible to run commands at your terminal. What I'm not sure about is whether running this script will have the effect you want, though. The `source` command executes code in the context of the current shell. Its effects wear off when the current shell terminates. The "current shell," in this case, is the instance started to run this script. When the script terminates, so does the shell, and thus so do the effects of sourcing the virtualenv file.

Comment: The line `SourceBinActivate=$Source $BinActivate` temporarily assigns the value `source` to `SourceBinActivate` then executes `/opt/ia3/bin/activate`. But `/opt/ia3/bin/activate` is not meant for running, it is meant for sourcing, hence it never had any execute permission. The `eval` line is a noop becuase `$SourceBinActivate` will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really have anything to do with executing Python code. There's no Python here. Your code is failing on this line:

```sh
SourceBinActivate=$Source $BinActivate
```

It's not doing what you think it's doing. You *think* it's assigning the variable `SourceBinActivate` to the value of expanding the two variables `Source` and `BinActivate`. However, what it's *really* doing is temporarily assigning `SourceBinActivate` to the value of `Source` and then *executing* the value of `BinActivate`. (The value of `SourceBinActivate` would be reverted to its previous value once the command finished.) Since that value isn't an executable file, your shell reports "permission denied."

To assign a variable to hold a multi-token value, you need to quote the value:

```sh
SourceBinActivate="$Source $BinActivate"
```

Comment: Rob - Thanks for that. That did the trick. I no longer received the Permissions Error after I added in the quotes. I was also able to complete the script and finish out my task. Apologies to for the confusion regarding tagging this / labeling this question as 'python' related. If it isn't painstakingly obvious, my "noob fu" is strong ;) The second half of the script runs actual python commands (I promise) so I just assumed source was also a python command. Thanks all for the help and this learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

If it's python code shouldn't be print instead of print ? Assuming your sample code is the "name.py" file. If your sample is indeed in a "name.py" file, try something like python path/.../name.py, and the call that from a "name.sh" file.

Edit: looking again at your code, it's not python at all. If python is the code you want to run, start with something small, something like:

print "Test" # print (string) in python 3.

The line above inside a .sh, then  do ./python_code.sh

Finally adapt your sample code to the python syntax.